# Copy output and extract number from it in perl

Tags: perl

I am working on a perl script in which I will run a command and get a output like : `your id is <895162>`. I will store this string and read the number from this string only . The problem is my main command will run in shell using the system command from perl .

like :

```
#ids.csh is "echo your id is <1123221>"
my $p = system ("./ids.csh 2>&1 > /dev/null"); 
print "$p\n";
$p =~ s/[^0-9]//g;
```

but the output is not copying to the $p file , Where I am going wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) runs a command but doesn't capture it.  For that, you want [qx](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#qx/STRING/)/backticks:

```
my $p = `./ids.csh 2>/dev/null`;
```

As Len Jaffe said, you probably want to throw away stderr output (rather than displaying it to your screen or wherever your stderr is going), but not stdout (that contains the message you want to capture).

Note that when qx fails, it can do so for several different reasons and constructing a meaningful error message is not trivial.  If you run into problems, consider using [IPC::System::Simple](http://p3rl.org/IPC%3a%3aSystem%3a%3aSimple#capture)'s capture() instead.

Comment: Now this command is printing the `./ids.csh 2>/dev/null` as ouput, I tried with system then it's printing the echo line but no copying it to $p and $p value is 0 if I print it.

Comment: then you didn't use backticks, you used single quotes.  backticks are usually on the same key on your keyboard as tilde ~.  Or you can just do `my $p = qx!./ids.csh 2>/dev/null!;` (explicitly specifying qx lets you pick whatever delimiter you want).

Answer (score 2):

You have redirected all of the output to `/dev/null`, which means that all of your output is being discarded.

I think you probably mean:

```
 ./ids.csh 2>/dev/null
```

Which will redirect stderr to /dev/null while leaving stdout unchanged.

Comment: Thanks but I want to store the result in to $p, Let say my ids.csh has just `echo "my name is toby1234"` so when I will run this file it will give the output `my name is toby1234` I want to store this in $p and then I will extract numbers from it.

Sorry for bad explaination

Comment: The difference between system() and backticks notwithstanding, redirecting your output into /dev/null means that the results of the echo statement will never be seen.